# Wrong query-result with R

Tags: r, odbc

From my 32bit-Windows (Vista) laptop I need R to query an MS SQL Server 2008 database on a 64bit-Windows (Server 2008) on another computer (via internet).

If I use SQL Server Studio on my laptop to connect to the database and send this query:

```
SELECT * from mytable where id = 1111111111111110032
```

I get the response
id, .....
1111111111111110032, .....

That is correct. I get the record I ask for.

But if I write this in R:

```
library(RODBC)  
My_conn <- odbcConnect("myODBC_connection", uid="abc123", pwd="abc123")  
tbl_Calls <- sqlQuery(My_conn, "SELECT * from mytable where id = 1111111111111110032")
```

I get the response
id, .....
1111111111111110128, .....

In other words, I get another record than I asked for (one that ends with ...128 instead of ...032). I know it isn't the query itself that is the issue, as it worked from SQL Studio.

I have no clue what could be wrong. Is the 32bit vs 64bit an issue? In my ODBC-connection I use "SQL Server" (6.00.6002.18005).

This is probably not an R issue, but I don't know where else to start... Maybe it is because the id is 19 numbers long?

/Chris

Comment: have you tried testing other queries to determine if it is this particular query that is giving you troubles, or all queries? Just thinking out loud here...FWIW I use a 32 bit windows machine and connect to 64 bit server w/o trouble on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try again, and now I think it is related to the number of characters in the WHERE-criteria (111...032, i.e. 19 characters). I did ODBC-tracing and although I don't understand it, I do get "-3, Invalid String Length". But how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and a "dirty" solution. The issue was not in the question, but in a faulty response of the id-field. I.e. the question and received record was correct, except the very long field I was using.

For the benefit of others, here is the solution.

```
tbl_Calls_2 <- sqlQuery(My_conn, "SELECT id, LEFT(id,10) as LeftId, RIGHT(id,9) as RightId from mytable where id = 1111111111111110032")
attach(tbl_Calls_2)
tbl_Calls_2$CorrectId <- paste(LeftId,RightId,sep="")
detach(tbl_Calls_2)
```

If anybody knows a nicer solution I'd appreciate it.

/Chris